# Cannot Preserve Menu Item on Screen Rotation

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I create a menu item (Spinner) in `.onCreateOptionsMenu` and want to preserve the selection on screen rotation. I understand it is common practice to use `SharedPreferences`, however in this case I am a bit confused as I do not create my view in `.onCreate()`, where I would normally load my saved preferences:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_bar_spinner, menu);
    MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.spinner);
    mSpinner = (Spinner) item.getActionView();
    int selectedPosition = mPrefs.getInt(SPINNER_SELECTION, 0);
    mSpinner.setSelection(selectedPosition);
    if (isOnline()) {
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getApplicationContext(), R.array.spiner_list_item_array, R.layout.custom_spinner);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        mSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        mSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                mPrefsEditor.putInt(SPINNER_SELECTION, i);
                mPrefsEditor.commit();
                switch (i) {
                    case 0:
                        mBaseURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular/";
                        calltoRetrofit(mBaseURL);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        mBaseURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/top_rated/";
                        calltoRetrofit(mBaseURL);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mIsFavoriteSelected = true;
                        mMovieURLS.clear();
                        retrieveMovies();
                        break;

                    default:
                        mBaseURL = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular/";
                        break;
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

            }
        });
        return true;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I am now receiving a null pointer when I try and set the orientation of the GridLayoutManager:

```
 if (savedInstanceState != null){
                glm = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(SPINNER_SELECTION);
            }
            glm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is perfectly valid to access SharedPreferences in other methods than `onCreate`. If you are experiencing some problem with this post the error message/issue.

Second, for preserving things when the screen rotates you can use the `onSaveInstanceState` in the Activity to save the spinner selection and get the state in `onCreate` when the screen is rotated. For example:

```
private int saved_selection = -1

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        saved_selection = savedInstanceState.getInt("SPINNER_SELECTION");
    }

    //...
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putInt("SPINNER_SELECTION", saved_selection);

    // call superclass to save any view hierarchy
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //...
    // set `saved_selection = i;`  in your adapter
    //...
    if( saved_selection >= 0 ) {
        mSpinner.setSelection(saved_selection);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought you can never implement any code before the call to super  in onSaveInstanceState?

Comment: No, there's no problem with that. You only have the restriction that "super comes first" in the constructor. See the examples here https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#save-simple-lightweight-ui-state-using-onsaveinstancestate

Comment: I am not having any luck, getting NullPointers now: https://github.com/troy21688/PopularMovies